# Add a Horizontal line on a static Row in sharepoint Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint list with some fields. When i click on new item it is opening a new form with some fields  to enter the values.

Here, on this page, i want to add a horizontal line on one specific row. How to do using jquery.

The code structure is something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top" width="350px" class="ms-formbody">
        <span dir="none"><select id="Evidence_x0020_Attached_fee083f0-60e9-4d66-bb36-2196a22a7923_$DropDownChoice" title="Evidence Attached" class="ms- RadioText"></select><br></span>
        <span class="ms-metadata">Choose Yes if you have attached your evidence to this form <br> <br>Instructions to Attach - Click on Attach File at the top of the page <br></span>
    </td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <hr />
    </td>
</tr>
```

So, I need to add this line dynamically:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <hr />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Care to share the code developed so far?

Comment: Please find the code below :

Answer (score 0):

CSS, where "3" represents the number of the tr:

```
.ms-formtable tr:nth-child(3) td {
    border-bottom:2px solid red;
}
```